# Странное изменение размеров окна Windows 10, large DPI

Tags: .net, winforms

В общем, проблема такова:

Имеется следующее окно:

[image: window]

По свойствам картина следующая:

- FormBorderStyle = **FixedSingle**
- StartPosition = **CenterScreen**
- ControlBox = **false**
- HelpButton = **false**
- MaximizeBox = **false**
- MinimizeBox = **false**
- TopMost = **true**
- Какие-нибудь действия, привязанные к отрисовке/изменению размеров формы - **отсутствуют**

У всех оно отображается корректно (так, как на скриншоте)
Однако один человек написал мне следующее:

> PLEASE make Custom Sorting windows sizable and/or properly assign dialog exit codes to windows buttons - they aren't visible with large DPIs and there is almost no way to show them or "press" using accelerator keys

Я попросил его прислать скриншот проблемы и увидел следующее:

[image: problem]

На нем четко видно, что размеры клиентской области почему-то порядочно ужались, так что кнопка и правая часть формы уехали в неизвестном для меня направлении

Что случилось, почему так... Не имею ни малейшего представления ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Так что вопрос таков:

1. Почему это произошло (виноват ли Windows 10, большой DPI или что-то
   другое и почему)?
2. Как это исправить?

Comment: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) - надеюсь, поможет. Еще вот, на всякий случай: [Disable DPI-awareness in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/disable-dpi-awareness-visual-studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Виновата комбинация свойств FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle и ControlBox = false с увеличенным DPI. По всей видимости, это баг.

Решение предложено [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1840ca5f-d4f0-4efa-9ad0-40e45734d831/autoscalemodefont-and-formborderstylefixedsingle-incompatible?forum=winforms): оставить ControlBox равным true в свойствах формы в дизайнере, а затем установить его в false уже в методе OnLoad.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, Вы всегда помогаете в самых непонятных ситуациях)